# spring: set property of one bean by reading the property of another bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Is it possible to set the property of one bean by reading the property of another bean? For instance, suppose I had:

```
class A {
   void setList(List list);
}

class B {
   List getList();
}
```

I would like Spring to instantiate both classes, and call A's setList method, passing in the result of calling B's getList method. The Spring configuration might look something like:

```
<bean id="b" class="B"/>
<bean id"a" class="A">
    <property name="list" ref="b" ref-property="list"/>
</bean>
```

Alas, this made-up XML does not work.

Why not just inject B into A? Because I do not want to introduce the extra dependency. A is only dependent List, not on B.

Comment: Since you have a better answer, would you consider changing your acceptance?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

in addition to @Kevin's answer if you are using spring 3.0 it is possible to do this with the new spring expression language

```
<bean id="a" class="A">
    <property name="list"
        value="#{b.list}"/>
</bean>
```

[spring 3.0 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch02s05.html#new-feature-el)

Comment: Is there an annotation friendly way of doing this without SPEL?

Answer (score 18):

There are a couple of ways.  Here is one:

```
<bean id="b" class="B"/>
<bean id="a" class="A">
    <property name="list">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetObject" ref="b"/>
            <property name="propertyPath" value="list"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also see the [`<util:property-path/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-property-path) element

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do the same for a constructor then do this.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" value="#{jdbc.dataSource}">            
            </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Here "jdbc" is as mentioned below that has property "dataSource" with getter and setter and initilized as:

```
<bean id="jdbc" class="com.la.activator.DataSourceProvider">
    <property name="myDataSourcePool" ref="dsPoolService"/>
</bean>
```