# Spring loading value from a POJO into an App context

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-annotations

Is it possible some way to load a value into a Spring appcontext.xml from a POJO?

For example, I have a POJO that is something like,

```
public class Settings {
    private String appSetting;
    getMethod;
    setMethod;
```

---

```
public class Main {
    @Autowired
    private Settings setting

    @Autowired
    private SomethingElse somethingElse
}
```

And the end goal is that I want `somethingElse` autowired with a value from setting. Is there any way to do this since I believe you cannot call methods in Spring?

Example appContext

```
<bean id="settings" class="com.myCom.settings" />

<bean id="somethingElse" class="com.myCom.somethingElse" />
    <constructor-arg name="something" value="VALUE FROM SETTINGS.GET" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component
public class Settings {
```

Check [Classpath scanning and managed components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) from the spring manual.

**Update**
You can use [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch07s04.html) as well. You can even mix your `applicationContext.xml` with the `@Autowired` you can for example wire by name or type.

Comment: See edit I made for app context. How do I get the value using @Component? I read the manual but couldn't seem to figure out how to achieve what I am looking for. I almost want to feel like it's the new @Value annotation but I'm not sure...

Comment: Added a link to SpEL. :) Depending on your use case the `@Value` could work as well. You are likely to need SpEL for your `@Value` annotation anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You could register the Settings component in the application context and then create a third class which is a factory for generating an instance of the SomethingElse class.  You could then wire the Settings component into the factory so it could grab the needed value(s) when constructing an instance of the SomethingElse class.  Like this:

```
<bean id="mySettings" class="Settings">
  <property name="importantValue" value="whatever" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySomethingElseFactory" class="SomethingElseFactory">
  <property name="settings" ref="mySettings" />
</bean>
```

Finally, you could initialize the SomethingElse component in the application context as a bean derived from a factory method like this:

```
<bean id="mySomethingElse" factory-bean="mySomethingElseFactory" factory-method="getASomethingElse" />
```

It involves creating a third factory class but will allow you to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but PropertyPathFactoryBean should help you . You could annotate the pojo with @Component and use the name "settings" to access it or could define a bean in your config file after you have done .

After this push the property into  "somethingElse" via PropertyPathFactoryBean  . An explanation is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602640/spring-set-property-of-one-bean-by-reading-the-property-of-another-bean) .Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="settings" class="com.myCom.settings" />

<bean id="somethingElse" class="com.myCom.somethingElse" />
    <constructor-arg name="something" value="#{settings.something}" />
</bean>
```