# Spring Dependency Injection - Using instantiated object

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Within Spring DI, can you "use" your bean within it's own definition? For example, if I have a bean called getTest1 with an inner bean declared within it, can I pass getTest1 to the constructor of that inner bean?

I'm wondering if I can implement a decorator patter-like solution using Spring DI for a work project but don't have much time to play around with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I think you need something like this

```
<bean id="a" class="com.AClass">
   <property name="aProperty" value="y">
   <property name="bean2">
      <bean class="com.BClass">
        <constructor-arg ref="a"/>
      </bean>
   </property>
</bean>
```

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602640/spring-set-property-of-one-bean-by-reading-the-property-of-another-bean) for more help on referencing one bean inside another

Comment: The scope of "a" is by default singleton . Hence I don't think a brand new "A" bean will be created.See [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78534-Access-enclosing-bean-from-inner-bean) for a discussion on this.

Answer (score 1):

The *decorator* pattern can be expressed in the following way using XML:

```
<bean id="decorated" class="Outer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="Middle">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="Inner"/>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This is equivalent to the following Java code:

```
Common decorated = new Outer(new Middle(new Inner()));
```

Consider Using `@Configuration` approach to make this more Java-friendly:

```
@Bean
public Common outer() {
  return new Outer(middle());
}

@Bean
public Common middle() {
  return new Middle(inner());
}

@Bean
public Common inner() {
  return new Inner();
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would also work for what I'm doing but I was looking for a way to shortcut and let Spring make my concrete class to be decorated instead of coding one. Thanks for the answer!