# Autowiring is not working when configured through XML

Tags: spring, autowired

```
class ConfigurationDetails {
    private @Resource String esHostURL;
    private @Resource int maxMessageCounter;
    private @Resource String queueName;
   // Assume : This class has all getter and setter methods and a default constructor
}
```

Another Class

```
public class SpringMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    @Resource ConfigurationDetails configDetails; // With getter and setter method for this
............
..........
```

And in my XML

```
<bean id="aListener" class="com.vzw.es.cosumer.SpringMessageListener" autowire="byName"/>
<bean id="configDetails" class="com.vzw.es.pojo.ConfigurationDetails"  autowire="byName">
    <property name="esHostURL" value="http://obsgracstg-db0.odc.vzwcorp.com:9200"/>
    <property name="maxMessageCounter" value="500"/>
    <property name="queueName" value="ES_queue"/>
</bean>
```

Now the bean with id configDetails is not getting autowired meaning when I debug the code and see the configDetails in class SpringMessageListerner it is showing null. But when I explicitly do the appContext.getBean("configDetails") it gives me the not null Object.

Why is the Autowiring is not working? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Show us your `component-scan`.

Comment: I do not have any component-scan element in my XML

Comment: Adding my whole XML here

Comment: I am unable to add whole XML here but for another bean in my project it is working perfectly, i.e. RabbitAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring doesn't, by default, look for `@Autowired`, `@Resource`, or `@Inject` annotations to autowire your beans. You need to tell it to look for them with

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourpackage.some" />
// or, in this case, <context:annotation-config />
```

with this, Spring will scan the classes in the package and inject beans for which an `@Autowired` or `@Resource` exists.

Don't forget to add the namespace declarations

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
```

More importantly

```
class ConfigurationDetails {
    private @Resource String esHostURL;
    private @Resource int maxMessageCounter;
    private @Resource String queueName;
   // Assume : This class has all getter and setter methods and a default constructor
}
```

Although you can autowire `String` and `int` types, this is usually considered bad practice. Instead remove the `@Resource` annotation here and add getters and setters for each of the fields.

The `property` element in the `<bean>` declaration takes care of setting those fields.

Comment: Now it gives me Exception : Error creating bean with name 'configDetails': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: @JavaCoder Good, we have progress. Remove the `@Resource` annotations on the fields of `ConfigurationDetails` and add getters/setters for each of those.

Comment: Its working now, Thanks a lot for your help. I have one more quick question, How to set a value in XML as a property of a different object e.g.

Comment: <rabbit:queue id="veliteQueue" name="ES_queue" durable="true" auto-delete="false" exclusive="false"/> and I want to get name property of above bean and set it to another beans property value like  <property name="queueName" value="${veliteQueue.name}"/> But it is not giving me actual value. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @JavaCoder You are welcome. Take a look at the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602640/spring-set-property-of-one-bean-by-reading-the-property-of-another-bean).

Comment: @JavaCoder You are again very welcome. Consider accepting the answer unless there is anything else.

Comment: @JavaCoder There is a small checkmark next to (below) the answer score. Click it. That tells other users that the accepted answer was helpful. You can vote on any number of answers, but can only accept 1 per question.