# Spring: Access bean property from another bean

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans:

ConfigurationManager:

```
public class ConfigurationManager
{
    private Configuration configuration;

    public void init() { ... } // Loads a configuration

    // Getters and setters
}
```

DataCenter:

```
public class DataCenter
{
    private Configuration configuration;

    ...

    // Getters and setters
}
```

I would like to get the `configuration` field of the ConfigurationManager from within my DataCenter bean and I'm not quite sure what the syntax is.

Here's my context file:

```
<bean id="configurationManager"
      class="com.foo.ConfigurationManager"
      init-method="init">
    <property name="configurationFile" value="etc/configuration.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataCenter"
      class="com.foo.DataCenter">
    <!-- <property name="storages" ref="configurationManager."/> -->
</bean>
```

Could somebody please show me how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602640/spring-set-property-of-one-bean-by-reading-the-property-of-another-bean?rq=1

Comment: @ChrisHayes, that did indeed work, my thanks! But I wonder, isn't there a neater way to do it with less boiler-plate configuration, or is this the only/correct way...?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef) to refer to other bean properties by name. Here's the example given in the docs

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.spring.samples.NumberGuess">
    <property name="randomNumber" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>


<bean id="shapeGuess" class="org.spring.samples.ShapeGuess">
    <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{ numberGuess.randomNumber }"/>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

In your case, you could use

```
<bean id="configurationManager"
      class="com.foo.ConfigurationManager"
      init-method="init">
    <property name="configurationFile" value="etc/configuration.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataCenter"
      class="com.foo.DataCenter">
    <property name="storages" value="#{configurationManager.configuration}"/> 
</bean>
```

In similar fashion, you can use [`@Value` annotation in `@Bean` methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations)  or [use it in `@Autowired` methods.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-annotation-based)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm afraid this example doesn't work for custom objects. I actually tried this first. It would work, if my field was for example, `String`, but it's a class called `Configuration`. How would I go about doing that? (Or maybe I've done something wrong)...

Comment: @carlspring It works with custom classes too, assuming you have the proper accessors. If you wanted to, you could also use constructor arguments and specify the type of argument.

Comment: @carlspring Honestly, I would actually have a `Configuration` bean, that possibly loads itself in constructor and pass a reference to that bean around instead of doing it this way, depending on your requirements.

Comment: @Sotiros, is there actually a way to define a bean which is actually a field/property of already defined bean? I mean -- if I have `beanA` and would like to define a new bean (`beanB`) that's a reference of `beanA.foo`?

Comment: @carlspring Isn't that what we're doing above?

Comment: No, in the above, I am injecting a field `f` of `beanA` into `beanB`. Could I get `beanA.f` as a separate bean `beanC`.

Comment: @carlspring If I understand what you are proposing correctly, that would go against the purpose of IoC and Dependency Injection. Instead of creating the `beanC` and injecting it into `beanA.f`, you're proposing creating `beanA` which creates `beanA.f` and then making a bean from `f`. In any case, no you cannot do this with Spring.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
<bean id="dataCenter" class="com.foo.DataCenter">
    <property name="configuration" value="#{configurationManager.configuration}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of your answers are correct. I am picking Sotiros' answer as it's a littler more detailed.