# Spring:How to access custom FactoryBean(AbstractFactoryBean<Properties>) properties in another bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, spring-el

I am trying to send an activation email to the customer after the registration process. I have created a FactoryBean implementation to retrieve the SMTP Server's emailId and password properties from DB as I dont want to hard-code the email address and password in config files or expose them as properties file.

```
public class MailPropertiesFactoryBeanRepository extends
        AbstractFactoryBean<Properties> {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private String tableName;
    private String emailId;
    private String password;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource) ;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    // Create an Instance of Bean Properties where we query
    // emailId and password details from the database to send emails to the customer.
    @Override
    protected Properties createInstance() throws Exception {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        String sql = "Select " + emailId + "," + password + " from "
                + tableName;
        jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowCallbackHandler() {

            @Override
            public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                props.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
            }
        });
        return props;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return Properties.class;
    }

}
```

Declaration in spring config file

```
<!--Declare Factory Bean to externalize the Mail Properties from Database ->
    <beans:bean id="mailProps"
        class="com.spring.shopping.repository.MailPropertiesFactoryBeanRepository">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="tableName" value="eshopper.emaildetails" />
        <beans:property name="emailId" value="UserName" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="Password" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I am trying to access the `emailId` and `password` bean properties in the `javaMailSender` bean as shown below

```
<beans:bean id="javaMailSender"
    class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <beans:property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <beans:property name="port" value="985" />
    <beans:property name="username"
        value="#{mailProps.emailId}" />
    <beans:property name="password"
        value="#{mailProps.password}" />
    <beans:property name="javaMailProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">
                smtp.gmail.com
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">
                true
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.auth">
                true
            </beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

The Service class to send the mail

```
    @Service
    public class MailSenderService {

        private final String FROM_ID = "info.demoproduct@gmail.com";
        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender;

        public void setJavaMailSender(JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender) {
            this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
        }

        public void sendRegistrationEmail(String emailId,String userName,String text){
            SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage  = new SimpleMailMessage();
            simpleMailMessage.setFrom(FROM_ID);
            simpleMailMessage.setTo(emailId);
            simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Activation Mail for "+userName);
            simpleMailMessage.setText(text);
            System.out.println(javaMailSender.getUsername());
            System.out.println(javaMailSender.getPassword());
            javaMailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
        }
    }

o/p:
null
null
```

My problem is I am getting the following exception

> org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   failed to connect, no password specified?

The `emailId` and `password` are printed as null in the console.

What is the right way to access the FactoryBean properties `emailId` and `password` in `javaMailSender` bean.

**P.S**

I have checked this answer for question
[Spring: Access bean property from another bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19194372/695657) .By debugging I came to know that I am dealing with a HashTable as java.util.Properties extends HashTable,and I dont have any idea how to access hashtable values through SpringEL

Thanks

Comment: Are they in the same xml file? If not try import the other one like <import resource="eamil.xml" /> at the other bean and try with this way.

Comment: @erhun They are in the same spring config file